# Is the algorithm behind std::seed_seq defined?

Tags: c++, c++11, random, stl

Does the standard require the output of `seed_seq` to be the same for different implementations of the stl? In other words, is the following guaranteed to produce the same output on different standard compliant platforms, or not?

```
std::seed_seq sseq = { 1701, 1729, 1791 };
std::array<unsigned int, 5> seq;
sseq.generate(seq.begin(), seq.end());
for (unsigned x : seq)
   std::cout << x << " " << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  The algorithm is defined in 23.54.7.1 [rand.util.seedseq]

<sup>posting this as an image as it loses formatting as text</sup>

> [image]

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Sorry for that.  I jusy could not figure out a way to format this as text and have it look close to the same as it is in the standard.  I do mention this is an image.

Comment: Verified that boost 1.52 and msvc2013 use that implementation (or a very similar one), at least at a first glance. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about, for some reason it just didn't occur to me that it's easier to make a screen-shot of this part due to the formatting :)